# Viewcontroller not getting pushed to stack

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, addsubview

I am fairly new to iPhone. I have a peculiar problem. I am adding a view controller as a subView to the current view. And then I want to push a new view controller from it. The problem is when I try to do pushViewController, it is not responding.

For example, in CurrentViewController I have added NewViewController's view as subView

```
[self.view addSubView : NewViewController.view]
```

Now From NewViewController, on the click of a button I am doing the following :

```
SecondViewController *secondVC = [SecondViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:secondVC animated:YES];
```

Here the secondVC doesn't get pushed to the stack.

Comment: Will a subview even have a navigationController?

Comment: @Jayashree. Have you used View controller appln or Navigation based application?

Comment: @Pugal : the CurrentViewController and NewViewController are View based and SecondViewController is Navigation based application

Answer (score 1):

If you have used view based application, You have to use this code.

```
  SecondViewController *secondVC = [SecondViewController   alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
   // [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondVC animated:YES];

      [self presentModalViewController:secondVC animated:YES];
```

If you want to use navigation controller in your appln. First you have to add navigation controller in your appln and then only will navigate the view.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the problem is that method is called `pushViewController` not `pushToViewController`. Try

```
SecondViewController *secondVC = [SecondViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:secondVC animated:YES];
// don't forget release here
[secondVC release];
```

Comment: hi. no that is just typo. i will correct it. but any other idea y this is happening??